# Execute on certain url format with strpos

Tags: php

I want to perform an action when the url is /bookings , but not /bookings/something-else

I tried this...

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/bookings') { 
  // do stuff....
}
```

But it fails when the user is on the /bookings page and searches, at which point queries are added to the url, e.g. /bookings?search=this

I have also tried this...

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/bookings') !== false && strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/bookings/') == false ) {
  // do stuff...
}
```

But this still executes on /bookings/some-thing and i cant figure out why?

Comment: `strpos` looks only for the occurence of the string, not an exact match. If you want exact matches, why not use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/bookings/'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this condition. first will make exact string. while seocnd match with query sring

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/bookings' || strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/bookings?') !== false) { 
  // do stuff....
}
```

OR use  === while matching false/ otherwise 0 and false become equal

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/bookings') !== false && strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/bookings/') === false ) {
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll be better off using a dedicated method for URL parsing, rather than using string manipulation. PHP's [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function is perfect for this:

```
$path = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);

if ($path === '/bookings') {
  ...
}
```